# Loading different header and footer in woocommerce templates (AMP)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, templates, footer, custom-header

I would like to use different header and footer in my woocommerce AMP templates instead of default one. I already achieved this but I can’t manage to do it for WooCommerce templates. So let me explain what is happening.

Website is using Storefront theme, and the current structure looks like this:
– for the desktop version:

```
/mytheme/woocommerce/
```

– for the amp version:

```
/mytheme/amp/woocommerce/
```

– In order for the amp woocommerce templates to load, I use this code:

```
 function woo_amp_directory ($path){
    if ( function_exists( 'is_amp_endpoint' ) && is_amp_endpoint() ) {
       $my_path = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/amp/woocommerce/';
       return file_exists( $my_path ) ? 'amp/woocommerce/' : $path;
    }
    return $path;
 }
 add_filter ('woocommerce_template_path', 'woo_amp_directory');
```

Now I have my custom header & footer in the `/mytheme/amp/` directory and I load it using

```
get_template_part('amp/header', 'amp');
get_template_part('amp/footer', 'amp');
```

However the WooCommerce templates are using the `get_header()` & `get_footer()` function which loads the header from `/mytheme/` directory. I would like to override this behaviour so the templates that are in `/mytheme/amp/woocommerce/` use my header and footer that are in the `/mytheme/amp/`.

Basically i would love to be able to use this:

```
get_template_part('amp/header', 'amp');
get_template_part('amp/footer', 'amp');
```

instead of default ones.

It doesn’t specifically need to use the `get_template_part()` function, i just want these templates `/mytheme/amp/woocommerce/` to use `/mytheme/amp/header.php` & `/mytheme/amp/footer.php`.

I already tried putting `header.php` and `footer.php` in `/mytheme/amp/woocommerce/auth/` but that didn't work.

Comment: In your header and footer templates, you could just use the same conditional you use in `woo_amp_directory()`. E.g. In `/mytheme/header.php` or maybe `/mytheme/header-shop.php`, you can do (at the very top) `if ( function_exists( 'is_amp_endpoint' ) && is_amp_endpoint() ) { get_template_part( 'amp/header', 'amp' ); return; }`. Or for example in `/mytheme/amp/woocommerce/single-product.php`, you can just use `get_template_part( 'amp/header', 'amp' );` instead of `get_header();`?

Comment: Yes i tried that but there were some errors with `is_amp_endpoint` function that was called too early. I fixed this issue, woocommerce was loading `page.php` instead of my custom template.